# I don't know why the boostrap.bat doesn't execute

Tags: boost, b2

Actually, I try to execute the boostrap.bat, but b2 does not appear and I still get some massage from boostrap.log. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bbO5.png)
How can I solve this problem...??

Comment: Are you using the Visual C++ Tools Shell?

Comment: No..I've just executed the bootstrap.bat from the "developer command prompt for vs 2019"